# How much above the cost price must he marks his goods above the cost price to make a profit of 17%

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A businessman allows a discount of $10$% on written price. How much above the cost price must he mark his goods to make a profit of $17$% ?

note:
$x\times\frac{90}{100}=x\times\frac{117}{100}$
$\frac{117}{90}\times100=130$
so $30$%
is this right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is a bit unclear, but you got the answer right.

If your businessman has a cost price of $P$, then to make a profit of 17% he should get at least $1.17P$ for his product.

Since he can give a discount of 10%, this $1.17P$ is 90% of the written price. Thus, the written price should be $\frac{1.17P}{0.9}=1.3P$. This indeed corresponds with a written price that is 30% above the cost price.

Comment: same as u written @spk 117*100/90=130 so 30%

Comment: why u persons are down voting?you are egoistic

Comment: discouraging others.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for this platform.

Comment: if $x$ is the cost price and $y$ is the written price, then $x+\frac{17x}{100}=y-\frac{10y}{100}$

Comment: Very difficult for the new user to edit . How you are editing this.I can see only bold italic ,hyperlink,images only in edit section.That is no use for sin theta,summation pi what to do for these symbols.It consumes a lot of time for editing always.When i can review the answer .waste site

Comment: Its very difficult to find the tag related and formula for editing the  posted question.